# aplicativo com tela Full Screen

Tags: java, html, android, app

eu não estou consigo colocar o meu app ficar em tela cheia e deixar apenas o botão de navegação.

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(

                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION

                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN // esconde a barra de status
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Veja se o seguinte trecho pode te ajudar (pode ser simplificado):

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    // o seguinte trecho pode ser omitido
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 11 && android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.activity)
}
```